# How to fetch text using reg exp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to fetch the text after / from the below code.How to achieve this one.I tried to find '/' location or index value by search() but it didn't worked.The scenario is i need to fetch the text which consists 2 parts as 'Username / some text'. Where user name is dynamic and i need text after the '/'
in HTML it looks like this (for one instance)

```
<a id="open_0" class="search-result-heading" data-gistname="15b6402d51d897f2ed29" "="" href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/edit.html?notebook=15b6402d51d897f2ed29">tejas1493 / ZZZZ</a>
```

i able to fetchText for the above but after fetching i need the ' / ZZZZ ' text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one...it might work. output will be ZZZZ.

```
path = "path of the selector";
var pos = path.lastIndexOf("/");
var name = path.substring(pos+1 , date.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it without regular expressions with a simple search as you described :

```
var text = document.getElementById('open_0').innerHtml;
var slash_index = text.search("/");
var first_word = text.substring(0, slash_index);
var second_word = text.substring(slash_index+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the below code will give you the contents in place of ZZZZ where Z can be a digit, uppercase letter or a lowercase letter.

```
raw_text = document.getElementById('open_0').innerHTML;
text = raw_text.match(/\/[ ]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+/)[0].match(/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/)[0];
alert(text);
```

Output: ZZZZ

NOTE: It will show the string all the way to the end of the text within that tag and not just 4 characters (if there are more characters).